# Get html from response text

Tags: scrapy, python-requests, httpresponse

I am trying to scrape a website that uses AJAX with Scrapy, I am sending a Request and I sometimes don't fully understand the result of the execution. This is my code now:

```
class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   results = []

   def parse(self, response):
       ...
       yield Request(url = 'https://www.books.com/ajax_more?book=book1', callback = self.parse_after_filtering1, dont_filter = True)
       yield Request(url = 'https://www.books.com/ajax_more?book=book2', callback = self.parse_after_filtering2, dont_filter = True)


   def parse_after_filtering1(self,response):
       try:
          jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)
       except:
          self.results = []
          return self.parse(response)

       response_string = jsonresponse['content']
       response = HtmlResponse(url=response_string, body=response_string, encoding='utf-8')
       ....

   def parse_after_filtering2(self,response):
       try:
          jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)
       except:
          return

       response_string = jsonresponse['content']
       response = HtmlResponse(url=response_string, body=response_string, encoding='utf-8')
       ....
```

Note that I use the try/except to avoid the error:
 `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Most of the times I get 3 Requests, all of them with code 200 OK and I get all the results I need. But sometimes:

**1**) The execution shows 4 Requests: First of them is a 200 Request (initial), second is a 502 Request (when entering parse_after_filtering2) and then third and fourth are 200 Request. In this case my results variable only contains the results yielded in **parse_after_filtering1**. Shouldn't it include all results?

Moreover, when the 4 Requests are: First a 200 Request, second a 200 Request, third a 502 Request and fourth a 200 Request, I get all the results from both parse_after_filtering1 and parse_after_filtering2!!!

**2**) Sometimes I get 3 Requests with status code 200 but only results from **parse_after_filtering1**. In this case spider enters the except part of parse_after_filtering2, but shouldn't it enter the except part after a 502 Request? In that case my variable `response.text` includes:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'MacroTemplateExecutord73621dd6570e9ea1a73cb2498fc5982' not found in <b>/var/www/html/lib/limb/macro/src/lmbMacroTemplate.class.php</b> on line <b>63</b><br />
<br />
```

Anyone can give me an explanation of what's happening?

Comment: Try `return` instead of `yield`. That's my guess.

Comment: it's the same, moreover I cannot use `return` cause I don't want to finish my code in that function, I edited my question so you can see I need to do multiple `yield`

Comment: When you get that `ValueError` message, what exactly is inside `response.text`? Can you print it out?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, thank you! I edited my question to include it

Comment: There is a `500 Server Error` how do you deal with unsuccessful requests?

Comment: I am not dealing with them at the moment. I have tried to surround it with try/except and repeat the Request but did not work, any suggestion?

Comment: @JorgeGarcia Do the same URLs always return that error? Or is it totally random which URLs and when?

Comment: Seems like is totally random... I'm using Scrapinghub and the error is returned 1 each 15 Requests. Any way I can do it without using JSON?

Comment: @JorgeGarcia In your previous comment you mentioned a try/except along with repeating the Request. That sounds like the general solution. Can you update your question to include what you tried there along with what is not working?

Comment: I have uploaded the question with the try/except I am using. Thank you!